# Troubleshooting remote installs of .ipa

Tags: ios, ipa, diawi

So using Diawi service and am able to install the .ipa but when I launch the app it quits immediately.
What are some troubleshooting steps to try? At the very least need to see some sort of error log. on iOS 13.2. Thanks!

Comment: Connect the device via lightning, open Xcode and view the logs via Window > Devices

Comment: thanks! Will accept as answer.